# Show/hide jquery using block / none

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anyone tell me how I can use this code to ***show and hide*** data between DIV`s (not to hide and show - I want the other way)?

I`m using in .js file:

```
function toggle(sDivId) {
                var oDiv = document.getElementById(sDivId);
                oDiv.style.display = (oDiv.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

And in .php file:

```
<div onclick="toggle('divContent1')" style="cursor: pointer;">Hide and show</div>
    <div id="divContent1">
    text here
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is working just fine but when the page is loading I wish to have text already hidden (not after when I click "Hide and show" text).

Thanks!

Comment: That's not jquery, and you can just hide the element with CSS or call your function on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
 $('#divContent1').toggle();
```

});

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XCyqr/)

Comment: Hey Thanks for acceptence .Please upvote and accepet as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code you have but just add `display:none;` in the css. Or in the php inside the `style="display:none;"`

```
<div onclick="toggle('divContent1')" style="cursor: pointer;">Hide and show</div>
    <div id="divContent1" style="display:none;">
    text here
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery has also a [toogle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function you could use.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EkxTa/)

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question, but if you want the text hidden on page load can't you just stick a display:none tag, as follows:

```
<div id="divContent1" style="display: none">
text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided isn't using jquery. If you'd like to do this using jquery you can change things to something like this.

```
function toggle(sDivId) {
    $("#"+sDivId).toggle();
}
```

and to your php block you'll want to add display:none; to initially hide the inner div

```
<div onclick="toggle('divContent1')" style="cursor: pointer;">Hide and show</div>
    <div id="divContent1" style='display:none'>
    text here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle`() function to alternately switch between `show`() and `hide`(). Otherwise, use the `show`() and `hide`() functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

call the function `toggle('divContent1')` at onload event of the body

```
<body onload="toggle('divContent1')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
function load(){
   document.getElementByID('divContent1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

and in your html

```
<body onLoad = "load()">
```